# Examples of equations that creates pseudorandom numbers

Tags: number-theory

I just want to know more examples of equations that creates pseudorandom numbers. Right now I only know the Elliptic Curves.

$y^2 = x^3 - 3x + b \pmod p$

Comment: This may help: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/29494/pseudo-random-number-generation-algorithms and http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random